# Android Studio: Displaying a list of pictures inside a folder?

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, apk

Alright, I am trying to display 170+ jpg images on the screen. So far my issue is having the app find the images and add them to a list. (I put all the images in the `mipmap-xxhdpi` folder because that seemed to be the only place where ImageView could find them)

Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList img = new ArrayList<Image>();
    File folder = new File("@mipmap");
    File[] fille = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i< fille.length; i++) {
        img.add(fille[i]);
```

> ```
>     ListAdapter picAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<Image>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, img);
>     ListView picListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
>     picListView.setAdapter(picAdapt);
> ```

I think the app is trying to find the picture in a directory on the android device instead inside the actual APK, but then again I have no idea. I am brand new to Java and Android Studio; the only prior knowledge I have is Python.

All help is appreciated, Thanks!

UPDATE: After googling for a while longer, I started to wonder whether if I could append an item from a `File[]` Array into an `Image[]` Array. Maybe the app found the pictures but couldn't append them to the list so the list stayed empty? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a URI URL to locate the directory of the picture instead. And then use an Integer array to store the image's id. And recall them as you need to via Id.